# Chrome Extension: can't listen for network calls made through service worker

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, python-requests, service-worker

I have built a chrome extension that listens for specific requests going to our server.
This has been achieved by:
- Adding a listener: `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(request)`
- checking the `request.type`
- checking the `request.url`

Everything works as it should, but I'm not currently able to get the requests being fired through a service worker, because the request.url doesn't match the expected one.

What should I amend in order to look at the correct parameter?
Is there another method/function to be used for service workers?

Comment: This is currently fixed only Chrome Canary, see https://crbug.com/914062. Meanwhile in older affected versions you can disable chrome://flags/#network-service manually. There might be some programmatic workarounds like utilizing an iframe (see the comments in https://crbug.com/933383).

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for pointing that out.
I'll wait for the new version to be published, as I can see it works as expected on v 74